# Xamarin on Visual Studio always rebuilds even if no code changes. It didn't do this before

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

A week or so ago Visual Studio, on my Xamarin Forms mobile app, started rebuilding the solution (Android project + Forms project) every time I run the app in debug mode. This happens even if there is nothing changed at all between two consecutive runs.

Before it did only rebuild the Android project on the first build of the day, or if I changed something within the Android Project. The other times it would just rebuild the Forms project and deploy to the device, even if I changed some code in the Forms project.

This is very upsetting as it takes a lot longer to deploy when rebuilding the Android project.

I've seen some sugestions of changing the properties in this window:

[image: Options]

But I think they are right, and I haven't changed them ever so I don't see how they would start impacting the builds without me changing anything.

I'm on VS 2019 v16.8.2

What else could it be that started this behaviour?

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help ->Send Feedback ->Report a problem**  .

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this post with a similar issue here is the MS ticket thread:https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-on-Visual-Studio-always-rebuilds/1305160 (at the time of this comment, no solution yet)